# Would replace by fee increase the fee on my transaction?

Tags: transaction-fees, replace-by-fee

I have a transaction with a $0.01 fee that has been unconfirmed for almost a day now, I got searching and found the replace-by-fee tools by Peter Todd.

I set up a full node with Bitcoin 0.12.0 and it's downloading the blocks right now.

Would the tools work to increase the fee? Is it safe?

The transaction is a deposit into some website, would I still get the deposit?

Comment: For your last question, only the website people can answer that.  It depends on whether their software is written to support RBF.

Comment: @NateEldredge Aha, another question (excuse my newbiness), is an RBF transaction sent with the same transaction ID?

Comment: No, the txid is a hash of the transaction itself.  Any change to the transaction (including a change in the fee) results in a changed txid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/5406)

Answer (score 2):

You can only increase the fee with BIP125 (opt in replace by fee) if your original transaction did already signal that it *can be replaced*.

If you made your transaction with Bitcoin Core 0.12, your transaction doesn't signal replicability.

Since Bitcoin Core 0.14 there is a global option called `-walletrbf` that makes sure, all your transactions do signal replaceability.

What you can do in your case is...

- CPFP (child-pays-for-parent).
  You can try to create a follow-up transaction with your change output of your original transaction that hasn't confirmed. The follow-up transaction should have a high fee. If a miner wants to mine your follow-up transaction with high fees, he must also pick your original transaction (an unconfirmed transaction chain).
- If it doesn't confirm, try abandoning the transaction (since Core 0.13) and re-spend your input
- Try to use -zapwallettxns (google)

Comment: I sent it with Blockchain.info, am I still able to do RBF or CPFP?