# Increase the fee for hanged transaction

Tags: pruning

So I made the transfer from my wallet’ address to other wallet. I use Bitcoin Core 0.14.2. And I read ["Would replace by fee increase the fee on my transaction?"](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51456/would-replace-by-fee-increase-the-fee-on-my-transaction)

I apologize, was mistaken and appointed the small commission. Transaction hangs as unconfirmed the fourth day. How many will hang and it will be forgotten for backward God only knows.

Thus, my small mistake can lead to dramatic loss of time. The key of command line "- walletrbf" (for use further "bumpfee") is incompatible with a key "- prune".  In general this key  does many useful keys useless. But I use 
 "- prune" for easy obvious reasons.

Can somebody explain, as it is possible to increase the fee of the outed transaction. Or to accelerate time of removal of transaction from network memory, spent it and a refund back to my wallet' address. I did not find any services for these actions in the Internet.

Comment: I don't see why `-walletrbf` and `-prune` should be incompatible. How did you arrive at the conclusion that they can't be used together?

Comment: For call "bumpfee.." in the console window I must start wallet with "-walletrbf" firstly. Yes, if I use both keys to start wallet  nothing happens. But after call "bumpfee.." I see notification that this command don't work with "-prune" mode and I need to start with "-reindex" command. It means I should wait aprox more one week for download full stack of blockchains. Unwanted hard case of overbombing. Nevertheless thank you.

Comment: Ah, I see. It might not have all the fee information in pruning mode. I'll have to ask around a bit.

Comment: The only command affected by -txindex is `getrawtransaction`. I don't see how it would have anything to do with bumpfee.

Answer (score 1):

P.S. After all above I closed BTC Core and started it again. I get notification like this "Blockchains integrity failured. Start reindex blockchains?".  I just click "Abort" button to close BTC Core and restart it. I get both tx on the right side in gray. But after 20-30 minutes old (conflicted) tx disappeared forever,  simultaneously the new (confirmed) tx **painted in black**. Long Life "Rolling Stones"!
That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Using opt-in RBF to increase your transaction's fee is only possible if the transaction was created as an RBF transaction in the first place. To that end, `-walletrbf` would have to have been active before the transaction was created.

For general advice on stuck transactions, please see: [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/5406)

Comment: Thanks. I see "Why is my transaction not getting..". What I get if used both commant line options "-walletrbf" and "-prune=600" I wrote above. Appropriate is obtained with deleting "mempool.dat" and trying start with "-zapwallettxes". Oh, "You have to use -reindex.."

Answer (score 0):

I find easy way to solve the problem without bumpfee, -rescan, -reindex..

1. I stopped Bitcoin Core and renamed my wallet (from wallet.dat to wallet.old) and deleted mempool.dat.
2. VERY IMPORTANT! I had backup my walled before sent with mistaken fee!
3. Copy this wallet in bitcoin wallet folder and start Bitcoin Core.
4. First time all my actions go on 5 min and my failured transaction (tx) came back. I repeat 1-3 points and made all less than 3 min. - created new tx with increased fee and sent it.
5. blockchain.info showed my old tx, and didn't see the new tx. I try find it by hash, recipient address etc. - all the same: Oops, non existent transaction..
   Ok, standby myself.
6. After aprox 10-12 hours I received the first confirmation of my new tx. At the same time old tx came back with cross icon. Right mouse click - on the bottom of context menu click "deny tx". Failured tx disappear.
7. After 1-2 hours my new tx get full confirmations and reached to recipient address!

Thanks to everyone.